# Magento 2.4.4 - Error Class does not exist during setup:di:compile

Tags: php, magento, compiler-errors, magento2

I am trying to run setup:di:compile on Magento 2.4.4, but I am getting a strange error and have no idea where to look or how to debug this.

Here is the code from the error log:

`Proxies code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% 1 sec 139.0 MiB Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% 1 sec 139.0 MiBClass "Magento\Framework\DB\DataConverter\SerializedToJson" not found #0 /public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include() #1 /public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile() #2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() #3 /public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists() #4 /public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass() #5 /public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract() #6 /public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php(61): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList() #7 /public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation() #8 /public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(216): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process() #9 /public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute() #10 /public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() #11 /public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() #12 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() #13 /public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() #14 /public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() #15 {main}`

Tried to redeploy static files and so on, but the issue still persists.

Thanks very much for your help!

I have tried:

- clearing generated folder
- deploying static content
- clearing cache
- reindexing

Answer (score 0):

What you can simply do is:

Remove the vendor directory and launch the terminal again and execute the command

```
composer install
```

to regenerate all the Magento standard codes. You can check your vendor folder to ensure all dependencies are installed and run the compilation command later to load the dependencies.

Please make sure to backup the previous folder as well for safer side.